# moment.js work out time left

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am trying to get my head around the moment.js library as it seems more stable than the jquery one and the jquery date one is output console errors.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

What i am trying to do is do a countdown to work out the time left from now.

example i have

```
var countDownTill = '2012-11-19 00:00:00 +0000';
document.write(moment(countDownTill).diff(moment(), 'months') + " months<br>");
document.write(moment(countDownTill).diff(moment(), 'weeks') + " weeks<br>");
document.write(moment(countDownTill).diff(moment(), 'days') + " days<br>");
```

which will output

```
0 months
1 weeks
4 days
```

but its not working out overall its doing it individuals for each value (days,weeks,months)

so if i up the date by say 12 months like below.

```
var countDownTill = '2013-11-19 00:00:00 +0000';
 document.write(moment(countDownTill).diff(moment(), 'months') + " months<br>");   
 document.write(moment(countDownTill).diff(moment(), 'weeks') + " weeks<br>");
 document.write(moment(countDownTill).diff(moment(), 'days') + " days<br>");
```

it outputs.

```
12 months
53 weeks
369 days
```

where as i am trying to get it to output

```
12 months
2 weeks
5 days
```

example here
http://jsfiddle.net/fDmWH/3/

Answer (score 1):

It's doing what you ask it to do. You'll need to reduce the countDownTill value with the number you just got. Code:

```
// Start date
var countDownTill = new Date('2013-11-19 00:00:00 +0000');
var now = new Date();

document.write(countDownTill + '<br />');

// Get the months
var months = moment(countDownTill).diff(moment(), 'months');
console.log(months);

// Add months to the date
now.setMonth(now.getMonth() + months);
document.write(now + '<br />');

// Get the weeks
var weeks = moment(countDownTill).diff(now, 'weeks');
// Seems like moment is doing something wrong here... it should be 0 weeks...
// 15 Nov to 19 Nov is 0 weeks to me at least...
console.log(weeks);

// Add the weeks to the date
now.setDate(now.getDate() + (7 * weeks));
document.write(now + '<br />');

var days = moment(countDownTill).diff(now, 'days');

document.write(months + ' months ');
document.write(weeks + ' weeks ');
document.write(days + ' days ');
```

Comment: hi asken thanks for the reply but from trying your code i am still getting the same output http://jsfiddle.net/fDmWH/5/ 12 months 53 weeks 369 days

Comment: yeah. you'll have to re-write it a bit. it's just pseudo code which means that it's only displaying how to do it and not necessarily that it works... which in the case it doesn't. i'll check the fiddle and change it so it works.

Comment: Updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fDmWH/6/. There seems to be a problem with moment though. I'm expecting 0 weeks as it's only 4 days but moment says 1.

Comment: hmmmm thanks i am finding some odds bugs appearing the more i use this library ;( going to try and fix this now

Comment: I'd say "stay away from weeks". they're bound to cause you trouble... do anyone but the swedes use those ;)

Comment: ok thanks asken im going to contact the author see i he can shed some light ill update